# Saving video created with Matplotlib's animation function taking extremely long?

Tags: python-3.x, performance, matplotlib-animation

I'm trying to create an animation of some video footage synchronized with plots of related data using the below code:

```
 def animatefunc(i):
    signal_idx = vid_idx[i]
    drawn_im1.set_data(image1set[i])
    drawn_im2.set_data(image2set[i])
    axs[1,0].set_xlim([time[signal_idx-100],time[signal_idx+900]])
    axs[1,1].set_xlim([time[signal_idx],time[signal_idx+5000]])
    markerline[0].set_xdata([time[signal_idx],time[signal_idx]])
    return
 frames = np.arange(len(image1set))
 ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig,animatefunc,frames,interval=1)
    
 writervideo = animation.FFMpegWriter(fps=10) 
 print(f'Saving... {datetime.datetime.now()}')
 ani.save(r'C://Users//...//Test.mp4', writer=writervideo)

 print(f'Done.{datetime.datetime.now()}')
```

The section of the code between the two datetime calls still takes 2+ hours for ~2000 frames regardless of how powerful of a pc I run it on. Is this normal or is there something I could/should be doing differently?

I read in all the images into a list and plot the full data series prior to calling the animation as shown above thinking maybe that was the source of the slowdown but it didn't seem to improve performance notably.  CPU and RAM usage via task manager indicate that I'm barely using any of my resources, do I maybe need to change something to allow python to access more? Running Python 3.10.12 via VSCode. Images are 12bit tiffs with a resolution of approx. 300x300.